# How to convert string with unusual format into datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using .NET 3.5 and I have a date that comes in as string in the following format:

> Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009

First question, what is the name of that format? Second question, what's the easiest and clearest way to convert this string into a datetime? I would love to be able to use a .net API/Helper method if possible.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I've already tried using DateTime.Parse and Convert.ToDateTime. None of those worked.

Comment: @jstawski: you have C# 3.0. There's no such thing as C# 3.5.

Comment: yep, you're right. Got confused with .net 3.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the DateTime.TryParseExact() method with a suitable format string.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

EDIT: Try something like this:

```
        DateTime dt;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); 

        if ( DateTime.TryParseExact( "Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009", "ddd MMM dd H:mm:ss \"GMT\" yyyy", enUS, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault , out dt  ))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString() );
        }
```

Comment: +1: Much better than accepted answer, as it demonstrates how to handle wonky date formats, unfortunately a pretty common occurrence.

Comment: Thanks OrbMan.  I've become very familiar with the DateTime.TryParseExact() method from dealing with a client that thinks they should be able to enter a date in a dozen or so different formats.  I actually use the overloaded version that accepts an array of string formats.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse("Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009", out dt)){
   /* Yay.. it's valid */
}
```

You can also use `TryParseExact` where you can specify the format of your DateTime

Using TryparseExact

```
const string FORMAT = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss \"GMT\" yyyy";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009", FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dt)) {
        /* is valid */
 }
```

I believe that should work. Not sure if it will try to parse out the GMT though.

Comment: This doesn't help me. It won't parse and it will return false leaving me back where I started

Comment: edited. Have you tried playing around with the format string?

Comment: Now it works and I like it. It ignores the GMT, do you know what the pattern is for GMT so we can include it?

Comment: There isn't any I could find. Here's a cheat sheet if you like: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: Solved the issue by doing dt.ToLocalTime()

Answer (score 2):

There you go

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009".Replace("GMT", "+00"), "ddd MMM dd H:mm:ss zz yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The DateTime API and its documentation pretty much sucks. Exceptions will only tell you that "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime", which doesn't really help. It had to figure out the date format specifiers myself because I didn't find them in MSDN.

The "en-US" locale is necessary, I guess, because your date format uses English abbreviations like "Tue".

Anyway, I can't tell you what the date format is called. It is pretty similar but not equal to a format used with HTTP (e.g. `If-Modified-Since: Wed, 08 Dec 2004 13:25:25 GMT`).

Comment: I should add that I wasn't able to cope with the "GMT", so I replaced it with "+00" which makes sure that at least the GMT timezone can be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx)

Comment: yes, I was elavorating, but my comment failed to insert. 
This doesn't work. Read my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a DateTime.Parse("Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009") and see if it accepts it.

Here's a good link for custom DateTime formatting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.TryParse(Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009", out objDt);
```

You need to give an output value. Use If and if it returns true then its a valid date.

HTH

Comment: returns false and i'm back where i started

Answer (score 0):

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo( "en-US" ); 

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact( "Tue Jan 20 19:47:43 GMT 2009", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT' yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None );

Console.WriteLine( dt.ToString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [DateTimeOffset.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343428.aspx) to specify the format of the date string.

Although, I wasn't able to quickly figure out how to match the timezone specifier (i.e. GMT). A look at a few Google results, shows that most people who are trying to solve this are doing it heuristically -- making a list of all time zones and the offsets and then parsing the string and replacing the timezone specifier with the +/- offset, or some other sort of hackish approach. Although, none of those solutions were from StackOverflow, so who knows how good they are.

Here's a short example I wrote, with the "GMT" stripped from the date string trying to be converted. If you could replace the timezone with the offset, add "zzz" to the format string. For the parse other formats, heres the MSDN page  [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) that lists them all.

```
// Parse date and time with custom specifier.
string dateString = "Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 2009";
string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy";
DateTime result;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

try
{
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime.Parse("Tue Jan 20 20:47:43 GMT 2009")
```