# Convert a string (format: yyyyymmddhhmmss) to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert string with unusual format into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610470/how-to-convert-string-with-unusual-format-into-datetime)

How can I convert a string to DateTime in c#? example:

```
string s = "20070406000000";
```

How can I convert that string into a DateTime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` method:

```
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact("20070406000000", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

This [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx) article explains how to do this.

```
 String MyString = "1999-09-01 21:34 PM";
 DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(theDateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", provider);
```

Comment: when parsing "20120302125057" the hour would be 0 instead of 12 - use HH for 24h format.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the DateTime.ParseExact function to tell it what the format of the string is so it knows how to convert it.

```
        string strDate = "20070406000000";
        string strDateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
        DateTime objDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, strDateTimeFormat, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```